# Convert integer to varchar and assign to variable pl/sql

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to assign a convert an INTEGER value into STRING and assign that to another variable, then use that variable later to display the value in text. Something is not going right and I'm getting an "String length constraints must be in range (1-32767)" error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
numdocs(usr_input IN VARCHAR)
AS
    user_name VARCHAR(20);
    num_docs INTEGER;
    numdoctext VARCHAR(20);
    num_converted STRING;
BEGIN
    user_name := usr_input;
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO num_docs FROM UserPermissions WHERE 
    UserName = user_name;
    SELECT to_char(to_date(num_docs,'j','jsp')) INTO num_converted from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line('converted is ' || num_converted);
    IF num_docs = 0 THEN dbms_output.put_line('No documents for ' || user_name);
    ELSIF num_docs > 0 THEN dbms_output.put_line(user_name || ' has permission to view ' || num_converted || ' documents.');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: What line is the error being thrown on?  What is the `string` data type.  That's not a built-in Oracle type.  Is it something that you've defined elsewhere?

Comment: I changed STRING to VARCHAR(20) and get this on my execute statements:

Error starting at line : 39 in command -
BEGIN numdocs('USAM'); END;
Error report -
ORA-12702: invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.NUMDOCS", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 1
12702. 00000 -  "invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function"
*Cause:    An unknown parameter name or invalid value is specified in a NLS
           parameter string.

Comment: I changed STRING to VARCHAR(20) and get this on my execute statements: Error starting at line : 39 in command - BEGIN numdocs('USAM'); END; Error report - ORA-12702: invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.NUMDOCS", line 11 ORA-06512: at line 1 12702. 00000 - "invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function" *Cause: An unknown parameter name or invalid value is specified in a NLS parameter string.

Comment: Don't create objects in the `sys` or `system` schemas.  It will cause you problems.  Various things don't work the same way in those schemas in part because they are designed not to have any user-written code.  Your next issue appears to be that you want both `to_char` and `to_date` to take two parameters but you're passing three parameters to `to_date`.  I assume you want `to_char( to_date( num_docs, 'j' ), 'jsp' )`.

Comment: SELECT to_char(  to_date( :number, 'j' ), 'jsp' ) FROM DUAL; was the example I was going off of to convert the integer to a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment:

> SELECT to_char( to_date( :number, 'j' ), 'jsp' ) FROM DUAL; was the
>   example I was going off of to convert the integer to a word.

And the code you actually display in the question, it looks like the issue is the placement of your closing parentheses in the code.  You put then both at the end of the "to_char", while the example has one after the "to_date".

So your select should read:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(num_docs,'j'),'jsp') INTO num_converted from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Demonstration and definition of STRING as type, at least in plsql.

```
create table string_tab(column1 varchar2(20) );
insert into  string_tab values('AABC');

declare 
  as_string   string(20);
  as_varchar  varchar2(20);
begin 
  select column1 into as_string from string_tab;
  dbms_output.put_line('as string=>' || as_string);

  select column1 into as_varchar from string_tab;
  dbms_output.put_line('as varchar=>' || as_varchar );

  if as_string = as_varchar 
  then 
      dbms_output.put_line(' and they compare the same.');
  else 
      dbms_output.put_line (' but they don''t compare the same.'); 
  end if;
```

Definition. The following extracted from package sys.standard:

```
  type VARCHAR2 is NEW CHAR_BASE;
  subtype VARCHAR is VARCHAR2;
  subtype STRING is VARCHAR2;
```

It's not used much, don't think I've ever actually seen it. But it is valid in plsql, doesn't seem to a valid SQL type!